# Spring Security 4 customize matchers

Tags: java, spring-security, matcher

I have some local services mapped to same base url part. This services for users should be closed, but one of its is used by ZooKeeper and should be open.
So i configured:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity(debug = true)
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  @Override
  public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth
        .inMemoryAuthentication()
        .withUser("user").password("us").roles("USER");
  }

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/inner/service/**").hasRole("USER")
        .and().antMatcher("/inner/service/event/bus").csrf().disable().anonymous()
        .and().formLogin().and().logout().and().httpBasic();
  }
}
```

this configuration does not works. i have open service not only for events. Each of services is open. If i change configuration to:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity(debug = true)
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  @Override
  public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth
        .inMemoryAuthentication()
        .withUser("user").password("us").roles("USER");
  }

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/inner/service/**").hasRole("USER")
        .and().formLogin().and().logout().and().httpBasic();
  }
}
```

All services are closed than.

Is it possible to configure anonymous requests everywhere

```
"/**"
```

authenticated services by path

```
"/inner/service/**"
```

with open one

```
"/inner/service/event/bus"
```

?

P.S.
Open service is used for ZooKeeper response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

solution is:

1. move to other path (to provide uncrossed passes)

   ```
   "/inner/service/event/bus"
   // for example
   "/inner/event/bus"
   ```
2. change http security configuration:

   ```
   @Override
   protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

       // to ignore csrf filter for zookeeper client api
       http.csrf().ignoringAntMatchers("/inner/event/bus");

       // configure the HttpSecurity
       http.antMatcher("/inner/service/**").authorizeRequests()
           // configure open resources. this configuration can be missed because of root level security (see line before)
           .antMatchers("/", "/index.html", "/inner/event/bus", "view.html").permitAll()

           // configure role for specified api
           .antMatchers("/inner/service/**").hasRole("USER")

           // to use default login and logout api
           .and().formLogin().and().logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/").and().httpBasic();
   }
   ```

this solution works also if i remove one instruction:

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().ignoringAntMatchers("/inner/event/bus");
        http.antMatcher("/inner/service/**").authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/inner/service/**").hasRole("USER")
            .and().formLogin().and().logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/").and().httpBasic();
    }
```

And one more important point (*i think important*).
I have removed from my ***.yml** files all security customization.